# How can I get the containing app when implementing a `UNNotificationServiceExtension`?

Tags: ios, ios-extensions, unnotificationrequest

I have one extension target and many product targets, and I want that one extension target to be able to be shared among all of my product targets and still be able to identify the app that will receive the `UNNotificationRequest`.

Is there a way to get at some unique identifier of the containing app through Apple APIs?  Alternatively, since the notification service extension is considered an embedded binary, is there some way I can have the build process inject some kind of value at compile time for the extension to identify the product target that just built it?

What I'm aiming to avoid is having `n` service extension targets for each of my `n` product targets.